# Deleted elements that I don't know

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, skype

In order to install a new version of Skype, I did

```
sudo apt-get -force remove skype
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This deleted lots of elements on my laptop and I don't know if they are important. Can you help me please?

Here is the list of the elements that I have deleted ([first page](http://www.pinterest.com/pin/119063983873733889/), [second page](http://www.pinterest.com/pin/119063983873733887/)):

[image: upscrolled screenshot showing list of package changes (top part of list)]
[image: downscrolled screenshot showing list of package changes (bottom part of list)]

Comment: Can't help wondering why everyone seems to remove the old version before upgrading. That's not necessary - it's a simple upgrade as we do with all other packages.

Comment: No, it wouldn't work without removing the old version. No point being arrogant.

Comment: If you previously had installed it from Canonical Partners, and now install the .deb from the Skype web site with `sudo dpkg -i ...deb`, yes, then you need to remove skype-bin first. I kind of assumed that you installed from Canonical Partners with a simple `sudo apt-get upgrade`. No arrogance intended.

Comment: That is not the question I was asking anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is simply how `apt-get autoremove` works.

`autoremove` simply removes every package that was installed as a dependecy, and is no longer required, e.g. the package that depended on it was removed.

It's nothing to worry about, if you encounter any dependecy problems, run this:

```
 sudo apt-get install -f
```

and you'll probably be OK.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
Everything seems to work fine, and Skype works as well. I was just worried that it might damage the "roots" of the laptop.

Comment: @VictoriaFew: I'm glad I could help. A tip: If you find the right answer, please accept it by clicking the "check".

Comment: So, autoremove never deletes anything we do need to run the laptop properly?

Comment: @VictoriaFew: No, it simply removes "dependecies" of removed applications which are no longer required.

Comment: Ok, you seem to know what you are saying so I'm going to try to stop stressing myself about it. Thanks !

Comment: Actually `apt-get` is saying it itself, try `man apt-get` and you'll find a bunch of info there. :D